# Как повернуть label на 90 градусов?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio

Как повернуть `label` на 90 градусов в WPF? Как сделать это именно программно на С#, а не в XAML-разметке.

Answer (score 7):

Попробуй `Label1.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(90);`

Comment: Или [`LayoutTransform`](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/03/211105.html), смотря что именно вам надо.